# Status of Shiro plugin with Grails 3?

Tags: grails, shiro

I have a number of Grails apps running with 2.2.5. I've been considering upgrading them to Grails 3, but I'm worried about plugin compatibility, most notably to do with the Shiro plugin which I use. From the plugin page I'm not convinced that it has been updated yet to work with Grails 3. Is there anyone out there using Shiro with a Grails 3 app successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The discussions regarding Shiro Grails 3 support is on going on [Github Shiro Page](https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/issues/44). As per the thread, it is not fully ready and developers are looking for help. Some of the developers were successful on developing a [Shiro Plugin](https://bintray.com/animator013/plugins/grails-shiro/) for Grails 3. However it lacks proper documentation and a sample demo application support.

I too had a dilemma of this when upgrading Grails 2.x to 3.x. What, I did was use the [Spring-Security-Shiro plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-shiro). It uses a hybrid approach combining Spring Security and Shiro Security, and proved to be handy.